# How to discretize steady state Fokker Planck equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

How to discretize a steady state Fokker Planck equation? For example

$$b(x)u_x - \sigma(x) u_{xx} = 0$$

subject to

$$u(x)\geq 0$$

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} u(x) dx = 1$$